# Splitting dataset into train and test

Tags: python, machine-learning

I downloaded this dataset with numbers and other mathematical symbols, which contains circa 380 000 images, split into 80 different folders, each named after the symbol it represents. For this project, a machine learning one, i need to get **train** and **test** sets which equally represent each symbol. For example **1/3** of the symbol folder in former dataset goes to **test directory** and **2/3** goes into **train dir**. I tried many times, but i always ended up with a ineffective code, iterating through every item, which lasted for ages and didn't even finish.

**The dataset:**
https://www.kaggle.com/xainano/handwrittenmathsymbols/

Comment: Can you provide some code you have been using? It'll be helpful to know what you have been doing and what kind of libraries (if any) you are considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset that you are using has extractor.py script that automaticaly does this for you

> ### Scripts info
>
> #### extract.py
>
> - Extracts trace groups from inkml files.
> - Converts extracted trace groups into images. Images are square shaped bitmaps > with only black (value 0) and white (value 1) pixels. Black color denotes patterns (ROI).
> - Labels those images (according to inkml files).
> - Flattens images to one-dimensional vectors.
> - Converts labels to one-hot format.
> - **Dumps training and testing sets separately into outputs folder.**

Visit its github here: https://github.com/ThomasLech/CROHME_extractor